# undefined reference to a function error 'linked lists', C

Tags: c

I have a function that sort a list:

Here is the declaration of the list:

```
typedef struct element
{
    char code[20];
    int capacite;
    char etat;
    int date;
    int nvols;
}element;

typedef struct avion avion;


typedef avion*  aliste;

typedef struct avion
{
    element A;
    aliste svt;
}avion;
```

and here is my function:

```
void sort(aliste T)
 {
    aliste P,Q;
    element temp;
    P=T;
    while(P->svt!=NULL)
    {
        Q=P->svt;
        while(Q!=NULL)
        {
            if(Q->A.capacite < P->A.capacite)
            {   
                temp=P->A;
                P->A=P->A;
                Q->A=temp;
                
            }
            Q=Q->svt;
        }
        P=P->svt;
    }
 }

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    aliste head;
    scanf("%d",&n);   // n is the number of nodes of the list
    
    head=create_list(n);
    sort(head);
    display(head);
}
```

ps: display and create are the functions that create and display the linked list

when i compile
i have the error: Undefined reference to 'sort',And im nt able to find out where is the problem. How can i fix it?

Comment: Show us where/how you call `sort`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: All those typedef makes your code harder to read.   You need the first typedef for avion to create the typedef for aliste.  It's ok to just write "avion *svt" in the `struct avion`.  Personally, I would just have written `struct element { ...}; struct avion { ...};`, and I am ok with the extra struct keyword when I need an instance of those objects.

Comment: Please show exactly how your functions and declarations are split accros files and how you call your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It probably just means that you need to link in your implementation of sort when you build your program.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a *function declaration* below your includes in the `.c` file ( i think all your code is in one file ?)

> **Function Declarations**

> A function declaration tells the compiler about a function name and
> how to call the function. The actual body of the function can be
> defined separately.

source : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm

Comment: The error message looks like a linker error.